# Android get pressed key on keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, keyevent

I would like get the pressed key on the keyboard, for all edittext etc..
For example I would log the pressed key in my test application.

How can do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the code:

```
       editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
            }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.toString().length() != 0)
            Log.d(""+s.toString().charAt(s.toString().length()-1));
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not work for the delete key for example if I press : "ab" and delete "b" I get "a" in my log and not the delete key code